# What does the TABLE function do?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I got a the formula `{=TABLE(C7,C5)}`.

I cannot find any table name from ribbon Name Manager, so I think there is no table. So, what is this formula doing ?

Comment: It could be a custom function. See if anything like that is under <ALT> <F11>

Comment: The Excel objects are only Sheet and Worksheet. Nothing is about "Table".

Comment: I googled this:  The formula was created by the Data | Table menu option. This option lets you create a "what-if" table that shows the result of varying one or two arguments in a formula. In this example, only one argument varies. You can only edit or delete the formula by selecting the entire range.  Source: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/99363-TABLE-function-in-array-formula-help-decipher-p-%28Excel-2002%29